# Python shell shows no error but program doesn't run

Tags: python, class, shell, oop, inheritance

I wrote this program to learn the basics of OOP. When I run this program from IDLE in the Python Shell it doesn't show any errors but also doesn't print anything... I'm not sure how to go about figuring out what my errors are.

Here's my code:

```
class Shapes(object):
    def __init__(self, width, length):
        object.__init__(self)
        self.setWidth(width)
        self.setLength(length)

    def getWidth(self):
        return self.width

    def setWidth(self, width):
        if (width <= 0):
            width = 5
        else:
            width = self.width

    def getLength(self):
        return self.length

    def setLength(self, length):
        if (length <= 0):
            length = 10
        else:
            length = self.length

class Rectangle(Shapes):
    def __init__(self, area, perimeter):
        Shapes.__init__(self, length, width)

    def getArea(length, width):
        return length * width

    def getPerimeter(length, width):
        return (length * 2) + (width * 2)

    def getStats(self):
        print("Area: {}".format(self.getArea()))
        print("Perimeter: {}".format(self.getPerimeter()))
        print("Length: {}".format(self.getLength()))
        print("Width: {}".format(self.getWidth()))


def main():
    print("Rectangle a: ")
    a = Rectangle(5, 7)
    print("Area:          {}".format(a.area))
    print("Perimeter:     {}".format(a.perimeter))

    print( " ")
    print("Rectangle b: ")
    b = Rectangle()
    b.width = 10
    b.height = 20
    print(b.getStats())
```

Here's what the Shell is doing, if you want to look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mys3H.jpg

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct this?

Comment: This is not going to work:
def __init__(self, area, perimeter):
        Shapes.__init__(self, length, width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call the main function. Unlike in C, where `main` function would automatically execute, in python, you have to explicitly call it; main doesn't hold any special significance and is just another function in python.

So at the end of your code, write:

```
main()
```

Once you run that, you will see errors like @Eric pointed in his comments, and many more.

---

There are many things wrong with your current code, here is a list of a few of them:

1. `object.__init__(self)` doesn't do anything
2. `self.setWidth(width)` calls the method, but the `setWidth` method tries to set to a variable that hasn't been declared yet.

   - So this needs to be corrected to

     ```
     def setWidth(self, width):
         if (width <= 0):
             width = 5
         else:
             width = width # and not self.width
     ```
3. The above is true for `setLength` as well.
4. Since you are using these methods to set and get values, you should look into using [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).
5. `Shapes.__init__(self, length, width)` is not the correct call.

   - You need to look into `super`
   - `length`, `width` are not defined here.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thanks so much! I got a few errors when I did that. Any idea on how I can fix them? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Rectangle.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Rectangle.py", line 44, in main
    a = Rectangle(5, 7)
  File "C:/Rectangle.py", line 27, in __init__
    Shapes.__init__(self, length, width)
NameError: name 'length' is not defined

Comment: @JosephWagner Check edits to my answer. The format for SO is one question per post, so I don't think I can answer more follow up questions than that. Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped so as to mark this as resolved :)